# Sencha Touch 2 list new page list tap response

Tags: javascript, list, dom-events, sencha-touch-2

I am learning Sencha Touch 2 and I have a list similar to [this](http://senchalearn.github.io/Presidents/) presidents list. Tapping the arrow loads a new page with a back button.

With my list, when I tap on the arrow I would also like to load a new page.

I borrowed some code from the presidents list which responds to a tap on an arrow and loads a new page in response. The code is as follows:

```
console.log('tap response! ');
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'article',
        title: 'testing title', //record.term(),
    });
```

The `console.log` responds so I know my function is responding to tap events on my list. However, the rest of the code fails with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'push'

The `this.getMain()`  function returns a reference to my main page which extends `Ext.tab.Panel` (I suspect that's my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`push()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-push) is a method on `Ext.navigation.View`. If you have a `navigationview` as what is inside of your `tabpanel`, you will need to get that view instead and call `push()` on it rather than the `tabpanel`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wonder if you know of an equivalent push function for tabPanel? The reason being, when I change to Ext.navigation.View it completely changes my entire app. As a learner, it's a huge problematic setback.